# I need help finding the sides of the parallelogram

Tags: geometry

In the parallelogram $ABCD$ the angle bisector line of the angle $\alpha$ cuts the segment $\overline{BC}$ in point $E$. If $\overline{CE}=3$ and $P=38$, find $\overline{AB}$,$\overline{BC}$,$\overline{CD}$ and $\overline{DA}$.

Comment: Could you please upload a picture of the question? I could not understand what $P$ and $\alpha$ is.

Comment: $P$ is the perimeter of the given parallelogram. $\alpha$ is simply the angle that a line bisects. That same line (if extended) cuts $\overline{BC}$ in point $E$.

Comment: I can draw a picture in LaTeX but it will take too much time (and I don't have it much). I hope it's clear now what I'm asking.

Comment: Is $\alpha$ angle BAD or angle ADC?

Comment: @SteveB That information is not given.

Comment: Then the problem cannot be solved. If $\alpha$ is angle BAD, $\overline{AB}$ = 8 and $\overline{BC}$ is 11. If $\alpha$ is angle ADC, $\overline{AB}$ = 3 and $\overline{BC}$ is 16.

Comment: Perhaps you are expected to assume that $\alpha$ is the angle at $A$, i.e. $\angle BAD$, in which case the isosceles triangle $ABE$ tells us which of the two answers of @Steve is the true one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Assuming alpha is BAD]

This shows the picture if $\alpha$ is $\angle$BAD.
AE bisects $\angle$BAD so $\angle$BAE = $\angle$EAD.
AD and BC are parallel, so $\angle$EAD = $\angle$AEB
Which means $\angle$BAE = $\angle$AEB and AEB is isosceles.
So $\overline{AB}$ = $\overline{BE}$

The perimeter is 38, making the semi-perimeter 19.

So $\overline{AB}$ + $\overline{BE}$ + $\overline{EC}$ = 19.

2*$\overline{AB}$ + 3 = 19, so $\overline{AB}$ = 8

And $\overline{BC}$ = 8 + 3 = 11